# Thymeleaf - Displaying a button after every two items in a list

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

brand new to thymeleaf. Below I have a table that in one column displays all the names (strings) in a list, and in the other column if the iterator is even then it displays a button.

```
            <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(names)}">


             <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>test</th>
                    <th>test</th>
                </tr>
                <tr th:each="string,itrStat : ${names}">
                    <td th:text="${string}"></td>
                    <td th:remove="tag" th:utext="${itrStat.even}? ' ':${button}" ></td>
                </tr>


            </table>




            </div>



            </div>
```

But all of the buttons are appearing outside of the table, above it. 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of the line 'th:remove="tag"' This works:

```
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>test</th>
                    <th>test</th>
                </tr>
                <tr th:each="string,itrStat : ${names}">
                    <td th:text="${string}"></td>
                    <td th:utext="${itrStat.even}? ' ':${button}" ></td>
                </tr>


            </table>
```